# How to delete this file?

Tags: 12.04, command-line, files, directory

I am trying to create a directory `.ebextensions`. Ubuntu 12.04 is telling me that there is already a file with that name; however, I have searched for it, and nothing comes up. I really need to create that directory ASAP. What should I do?

Comment: Can you see the file using `ls -a`?

Comment: No, can't find it, @troylatroy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To see dot or hidden files, use

```
ls -Al
```

To see just this file, use

```
ls -Al .ebextensions
```

To remove it, use

```
rm -rf .ebextensions
```

Just take care with those "-rf" options, because they can delete everything without asking if you type them wrong.

Also, on your file browser, configure it to show hidden files and you can delete it graphically.

Comment: @bohdi.zazen, OK. I put the 2nd command into terminal... And it says `ls: cannot access .ebextension: No such file or directory`. What now?

Comment: I just tried that. It came back with the following: mkdir: cannot create directory `.ebextensions': File exists

Comment: Ah, OK. It says `total 0` to the 2nd command

Comment: `rm -rf .ebextensions` with an s at the end

Comment: `@bodhi.zazen === genius`

Answer (score 2):

To view files and directories starting with a `.` in nautilus, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>.

To delete a file in the terminal, use the [`rm`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man1/rm.1.html) command: `rm .ebextensions`

Comment: I am in terminal